# How to make my request.method==post work? my code goes to else code and logs me out to home screen.I am unable to take users information

Tags: python, django

> when create page opens up, even if i don't fill any information ,it does'nt gives me the error all fields are required , rather every time it logs me out and goes to home page. I think my if(request.method==post) block is not processed at all,rather it logs me out , and takes me back to my signup/home page

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import Product
from django.utils import timezone

def home(request):
    return render(request,'products/home.html')

@login_required
def create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST['title'] and request.POST['body'] and request.POST['url'] and request.FILES['icon'] and request.FILES['image']:
            product = Product()
            product.title=request.POST['title']
            product.body=request.POST['body']
            if request.POST['url'].startswith('http://') or request.POST['url'].startswith('https://'):
                product.url=request.POST['url']
            else:
                product.url= 'http://'+ request.POST['url']
            product.icon=request.FILES['icon']
            product.image=request.FILES['image']
            product.pub_date= timezone.datetime.now()
            product.hunter=request.user
            product.save()
            return redirect('create')
        else:
            return render(request,'products/create.html',{'error':'All fields are required'})




    else:
        return render(request,'products/create.html')
```

Comment: Have you checked what request.method is at runtime?

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: Right before the if statement, write: print(request.method). You can also use a debugger but this should do for now

Comment: Why don't you create a form to pass to the view it is easier to check for errors

Comment: it isn't working . as soon as i click on add product(add product is a submit button in html) it logs me out and takes me to home /signup page

Comment: If you are using the decorator `@login_required,` and you are not logged in, it will redirect you to the login page. It won't be because it doesn't proccess `if(request.method==post)`, since the whole function won't execute. Why do you thing it logs you out rather than you are not logged in at all?

Comment: i am accessing the create page after login only . you can't access a page without login in which login is required.

Answer (score 0):

Did you log in with your user? You'd need to do have a separate view function which will authenticate your user and keep the user logged in to a session. Suggesting this since I don't see any login view function or any reference on how you're logging in your app.

**EDIT: How to login using django (from the docs)**

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def my_view(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
    else:
        # send a message to show user is not logged in
        pass
```